# error code #1064 while Declaring Cursor in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cursor

It's my first time working with cursors on MySQL, and I am having some problems, it doesn't accept the declaration of my cursor, what's wrong with my code? it shows me this error messagae:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR' at line 1

and my code is:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField varchar2(255);

BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT codeMaint from affectationmc where iduser=29;     

    OPEN @MyCursor 
        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
        INTO @MyField

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
          delete from mcorr where codemaint=@MyField ;
          FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
          INTO @MyField 
        END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;

    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the template I use for cursors.  It just taking the items from the select and maps them into the variables declared up top and executes your statement.  Once it processes the statement in the section --Actions to Loop Here, it changes the variables by selecting the next row from your select statement. This repeats until it process all of the rows in the select.

```
DECLARE 

 @variable_A AS varchar(15)
,@variable_B AS INT
,@variable_C AS INT
,@variable_D AS VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE Process_Name CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
            SELECT 
                        T.Col_A,T.Col_B,T.Col_C,T.Col_D
            FROM 
                        tab.my_table AS T;


OPEN Process_Name 
FETCH NEXT FROM Process_Name INTO @variable_A,@variable_B,@variable_C,@variable_D

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


--Actions to Loop Here


FETCH NEXT FROM Process_Name INTO @variable_A,@variable_B,@variable_C,@variable_D
END

CLOSE Process_Name 
DEALLOCATE Process_Name
```

Comment: please attach the modified query for review.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to declare your cursor in one statement, then associate the query with it in a second statement. While some databases will allow this, I'm fairly sure MySQL isn't one of them. Also, MySQL is quite strict about not declaring cursors until *after* all variables have been declared.

Here's how I would do it:

```
BEGIN  -- note all declarations are inside the BEGIN/END
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;  -- Good practice is to avoid global variables whenever possible
  DECLARE MyField varchar(255); -- varchar2 is Oracle, not MySQL

  DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT codeMaint
      FROM affectationmc
      WHERE iduser = 29;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET done = TRUE;  -- this will detect end-of-result-set

  OPEN MyCursor;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH NEXT
      FROM MyCursor 
      INTO MyField;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    DELETE FROM mcorr
      WHERE codemaint = MyField ;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE MyCursor;
END;
```

Comment: @Bashir try Darwins solution. I'm a T-SQL guy so my syntax may not have been valid as Darwin has mentioned.